# How To Declare JSON Fields in a Django Model?

Tags: mysql, json, django

I'm seeking to create my first Django mySQL model that contains a JSON field.

I've read the docs [here](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html), but they don't seem to show an example of how to declare a model that contains multiple fields, including JSON fields. I've done a lot of searches on Google and SO, but haven't yet found examples.

What would be the correct way to declare a model that would store data like this?

```
candy_bar_name='Snickers',
info={
    'target_markets': [
        {
            'market_type': 'type_a',
            'included_markets': [array of strings]
        },
        {
            'market_type': 'type_b',
            'included_markets': [array of strings]
        },
        {
            'market_type': 'type_c',
            'included_markets': [array of strings]
        },
    ],
}
```

**UPDATE 2-13-2020**

Responding to comment from @iklinac --

Thanks for this comment. I see this:

```
from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model

class ShopItem(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attrs = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

...but I'm confused by this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can a model with multiple fields return a single string? I thought possibly this might be a class that defines a single JSON field in a model defined elsewhere. ;)

**UPDATE 2-14-2020**

This has now been solved via the help of the comments to this post. This works:

```
from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model

class CandyBars(models.Model):
    candy_bar_name = models.TextField()
    info = JSONField()
```

Comment: First example in docs has 2 different fields in model ( 1 charfield, and 1 jsonfield) can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve

Comment: `__str__(self)` is just a string representation of the object, for debugging purposes mostly

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

Comment: Also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models

Comment: Thanks! This is working now. If `iklinac` or `Horatiu Jeflea` would care to post the info as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.